# Anyway to round up to the nearest integer in a list in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Hi sorry if this question has already been answered somewhere else. I am working on a one of my first major personal projects and I've kind of got stumped. Right now my program will generate a list of numbers that correspond to a type. For example type X generates the numbers below and Type Y generate its own list of numbers (I've simplified this for explanations sake).

```
case ("x"):
                    temp.AddLast(1);
                    temp.AddLast(8);
                    temp.AddLast(16);
                    temp.AddLast(20);
                    temp.AddLast(23);
                    temp.AddLast(26);
                    temp.AddLast(29);
                    break;

case ("y"):
                    temp.AddLast(2);
                    temp.AddLast(5);
                    temp.AddLast(11);
                    temp.AddLast(17);
                    temp.AddLast(23);
                    temp.AddLast(28);
                    break;
```

Then my program will take an object that has a Type and an Integer and round up or down to the closest number depending on another condition.

```
Object o = new Object(Type, Value, Rounding);
```

I've tried using LINQ but I always run into the issue of my numbers not rounding correctly. ***I can't change the numbers I'm using*** so I was wondering if there is anything I can do to make this round in the way that I want.

I would really appreciate any advice I can get on this. Thank you!

***EDIT***

Sorry for not being clear!

So what I am trying to accomplish is to have my program accept an object, which is already has predefined properties and values from a database, but that's besides the point.

It will look at the Type (X or Y on the above example), and generate a list based on that Type (The Switch Case in my example). Then my program is suppose to take the Value and find the next highest integer.

EX. If my Object:

```
Object o = new Object(X, 8, Up);
```

The result that would be displayed would be 16.

The issue that I'm running into is that I'm trying to 'round' it up, but I keep getting the closest value, not the next highest value, if that makes sense.

So far I've tried to using the Math().Round methods, but because I'm dealing with ints that didn't really help all that much. I tried to do some research on here before asking but I didn't find anything useful.

Comment: "numbers not rounding correctly" - can you clarify this? It'd help if you provide a complete example of the problem, along with how you expect it to behave.

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear, where is the rounding? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Do you mean that if you enter 4, it should choose 5? Or if you enter 3 it should choose 2?

Comment: Since you're using confusing terminology (an integer is, by definition, a whole number - there is no fractional component to round), it would be better to provide example inputs and outputs based on `temp` to illustrate what you're actually asking.

Comment: I've edited my post, I hope it makes more sense. Sorry again!

Comment: Can you also include the solution(s) that you've tried so far?

Comment: What result would you expect from `new Object(X, 100, Up)`?

Comment: @devNull I edited my post, but I've really only tried Math() and List.Aggregate(), but I really didn't understand the latter all too well

Comment: @DourHighArch It should respond with the highest value on the list, if the Object value is higher than any number on it.

Comment: If your question is "how do I find a value in a sorted list that's higher than some value or the last value on the list if it's higher than all of them?" then ask _that_ question. Questions should be the minimal code to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Up` option, you can search `temp` to look for the value that is greater than your value and take it.

```
for (int i = 1; i < temp.Count; i++)
    if (temp [i] > value)
    {
        value = temp[i];
        break;
    }
```

If your value is grater than or equal the last value, you take the last value:

```
if (value >= temp[temp.Count - 1])
    value = temp[temp.Count - 1];
```

And you can do the opposite for `Down` option.

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked perfectly for doing the Up and was a great base for the Down search! Thank you again, I really appreciate it!